# How to filter out from a repetition pattern?

Tags: rust, macros

I try to generate a struct from a macro looking like that:

```rust
decl_struct! {
    MyStruct {
        mut foo,
        const bar,
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to filter out the fields marked as `const`. I have tried with the following code, but it does not function due to the fact that the outer macro is evaluated first:

```rust
macro_rules! decl_struct {
    {
        $name:ident {
            $( $kind:ident $member:ident, )*
        }
    } => {
        decl_struct!(@gen_struct $name { $( decl_struct!(@gen_struct_member $kind $member) )* } );
    };

    // Filters the `const` members out:
    (@gen_struct_member mut $member:ident) => ($member,);
    (@gen_struct_member const $member:ident) => ();
    
    // Generate the whole struct:
    {
        @gen_struct $name:ident {
            $( $member:ident, )*
        }
    } => {
        struct $name {
            $( $member:ident : u32 /*Dummy type*/, )*
        }
    };
}

decl_struct! {
    MyStruct {
        mut foo,
        const bar,
    }
}
```

[Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8669f2afc95d974a4462eb5c5a3b2d56).

What can be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html):

> Macros can expand to expressions, statements, items (including traits, impls, and foreign items), types, or patterns.

Notably, they can't expand to singular field definitions (as attempted by your `@gen_struct_member` invocations).  However, for your particular problem, you can instead simplify to a single macro invocation with a bit of clever repetition:

```rust
macro_rules! decl_struct {
    {
        $name:ident {
            $( const $initial:ident, )*
            $(
                mut $mut:ident,
                $( const $const:ident, )*
            )*
        }
    } => {
        struct $name {$(
            $mut: u32,
        )*}
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19f16306ca50384f05276af8775f7e82).

Comment: That's a clever trick. Too bad that in my real code I have 3 different "modifiers".

Comment: Unfortunately this fails in the case where you use two `mut` in a row. On encountering the second `mut`, the parser can't decide whether to put it in the current `$()+` repetition, or to end that one and start a new outer `$()*`.

Comment: @zelk: Actually, I'm not too sure now why I put the repetition around the `mut`.  I've updated the answer, which now works for consecutive `mut`s.